# how to decrease CPU usage when using multiple threads VB.net?

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I am using vb.net , .NetFramework 2.0 .

My application gets live stock prices from google and updates stocks in database each 10 seconds.

I get this code for  multithreading. When application starts updating stocks in database(about 200 stocks) , the update takes up to 3 seconds but it increase CPU usage from 10 % to 70 % or 80 %.

What is the best way to to update database without getting CPU increase to high level?

I observed that all threads works at the same time. how to make each thread wait until the second ends?

This is my code. The problem is in function updateThreaded2().

Please I need quick help. Thanks

```
Public Function Update2(ByVal l As SortableBindingList(Of NewStockList)) As Long
    res = 0
    UThread = New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf UpdateThreaded2)
    If Me.URunning = True Then
    Else
        Try
            Me.URunning = True
            Interlocked.Exchange(Me.UCount, 0)  'threadsafe method of assigning static value
            Interlocked.Exchange(Me.UDone, 0)   'threadsafe method of assigning static value
            UThread.Priority = Threading.ThreadPriority.BelowNormal
            UThread.IsBackground = True
            UThread.Start(l)
            Return 0
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    End If
End Function




Private Sub UpdateThreaded2(ByVal l As SortableBindingList(Of NewStockList))

    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Dim threadcount As Integer = Math.Min(Me.MaxThreads, Me.Stocks.Count)
    Dim threads(threadcount - 1) As SUTC
    Try
        While i < Me.Stocks.Count
            For j As Integer = 0 To threadcount - 1
                If threads(j) Is Nothing Then
                    If i < Me.Stocks.Count Then
                        threads(j) = New SUTC(Me.Stocks(i), Me.DefaultService, AdjustSplits, Use20Minutes, l)
                        threads(j).Thread.Priority = Threading.ThreadPriority.BelowNormal
                        threads(j).Thread.IsBackground = True
                        threads(j).Thread.Start()

                        i += 1
                    End If
                ElseIf threads(j).UpdateState = 0 Then
                    If i < Me.Stocks.Count Then
                        SecUpd(j) = Me.Stocks(i).symbol
                        threads(j) = New SUTC(Me.Stocks(i), Me.DefaultService, AdjustSplits, Use20Minutes, l)
                        threads(j).Thread.Priority = Threading.ThreadPriority.BelowNormal
                        threads(j).Thread.IsBackground = True
                        threads(j).Thread.Start()
                        i += 1

                    End If
                End If
            Next

            Dim running As Boolean = True
            While running
                For j As Integer = 0 To threadcount - 1
                    If threads(j).UpdateState = 0 Then
                        Thread.Sleep(10)
                        running = False
                        SecUpd(j) = ""
                        Interlocked.Increment(UDone)  'threadsafe method of incrementing a variable by 1
                        Interlocked.Exchange(UCount, UCount + threads(j).UpdateCount)   'Threadsafe method for assigning a value
                    End If
                Next
            End While
        End While

        Dim pending As Integer = threadcount
        Dim tempcount As Integer = 0
        Dim oldcount As Integer = UCount

        While pending > 0
            pending = threadcount
            tempcount = 0
            For i = 0 To threadcount - 1
                If threads(i).UpdateState = 0 Then
                    SecUpd(i) = ""
                    pending -= 1
                    tempcount += threads(i).UpdateCount
                    Thread.Sleep(10)
                End If
            Next
            Interlocked.Exchange(UDone, Me.Stocks.Count - pending)  'Threadsafe method for assigning a value
            Interlocked.Exchange(UCount, oldcount + tempcount)      'Threadsafe method for assigning a value
        End While

        Me.URunning = False
    Catch ex As System.Threading.ThreadAbortException   'handle abort correctly
        Dim pending As Integer = threadcount
        Dim tempcount As Integer = 0
        Dim oldcount As Integer = UCount
        While pending > 0
            pending = threadcount
            tempcount = 0
            For i = 0 To threadcount - 1
                If threads(i).UpdateState = 0 Then
                    SecUpd(i) = ""
                    pending -= 1
                    tempcount += threads(i).UpdateCount
                End If
            Next
            Interlocked.Exchange(UDone, Me.Stocks.Count - pending)  'Threadsafe method for assigning a value
            Interlocked.Exchange(UCount, oldcount + tempcount)      'Threadsafe method for assigning a value
        End While
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: Use a background worker, they are for long running processes...

Comment: It might help you in general to remove the `Catch ex As Exception` from your code. They are worse than `Goto` and make code very hard to debug.

Comment: Thanks, I will remove them

Answer (score 0):

This is fantastically simplified, but threads by their nature will run at the same time (if possible and depending to some extent on the whim of the OS).  If you want less going on simultaneously, use fewer threads.  In your case, since you want the jobs done sequentially, you really only want one thread.

The best approach, as mentioned, is to create a background worker that runs on a single background thread.  There's usually a queue to which you submit jobs in a thread-safe way from the foreground thread.  The thread proc typically runs in an infinite loop, processing each job in the queue, and going to sleep waiting for new jobs when there are none.